# Spring Boot logging pattern

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I have a problem with configuration on Logback in a Spring Boot application. I want my `consoleAppender` to look like the default Spring Boot console appender. How to inherit pattern from Spring Boot default console appender?

Below is my `consoleAppender` configuration

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern class="org.">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Maybe you should follow issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1788 - this may give you a solution when closed.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Once you have included the default configuration, you can use its values in your own `logback-spring.xml` configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- use Spring default values -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    …
</configuration>
```

Comment: Don't forget adding `<root level="INFO"><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></root>`, otherwise you won't get anything logged

Comment: That’s what you put instead of the ellipsis.

Comment: as jediz said above, this solution logs nothing unless you add `<root level="INFO"><appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/></root>`

Comment: Probably you also want to add ```packagingData="true"``` in ```<configuration>``` for package names in exception log messages as it is the default with Spring Boot logging.

Comment: If the desire is to use the Spring default values, then instead of `utf8` the default value `CONSOLE_LOG_CHARSET` can be used as well

Answer (score 49):

You can find Spring Boot logback console logging pattern in defaults.xml file:

> spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml

Console pattern:

```
<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
```

Comment: what does LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD do?

Comment: This pattern goes through some variable substitution resulting in a different pattern

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml

Comment: ^^ I had to replace `:-` with `:` when I copied the latest log pattern from above Spring defaults.xml in order for it to work in my application.properties file (as `logging.pattern.console` and `logging.pattern.file`).  `:-` is a Logback thing and `:` is a Spring thing.

Comment: @AlexanderTaylor you, sir, are a literal lifesaver. Kudos, I would have never found this really ugly prerequisite. 
If this is not done, all log lines were prepended with "--" (SpringBoot 2.7.12)

Answer (score 19):

If you are using *application.yml* for your config, you can set the logging pattern this way:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | %-5level | %logger{1.} | %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework: WARN
    com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot: WARN
    com.example.test: DEBUG
```

You can override the logging level on the command line. For example:

```
$ java -Dlogging.level.com.example.test=TRACE -jar my-example.jar
```

Comment: Thank you, I needed to update this without creating a whole logback config file so this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="clr" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wex" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="wEx" converterClass="org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: are those conversion rules supposed to bring spring-defined colouring to logback? It's not working for me

Answer (score 11):

It's been some time since this question was asked but since I had the problem myself recently and couldn't find an answer I started digging a bit deeper and found a solution that worked for me.

I ended up using the debugger and take a look at the default appenders attached to the logger.

I found this pattern to be working as desired for me:

```
<pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p 18737 --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wEx</pattern>
```

EDIT: The pattern is not entirely correct, I saw that runtime some values had already been instantiated (in this case 18737  ---) i will look into the proper variable to substitute there. It does contain the format for fixed length columns though

EDIT 2: Ok, I took another look at the debugger contents. This you can also do yourself by looking at the contents of a logger instance:
[Debugger(eclipse) Logger Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWU3z.png)

So I ended up using the pattern used in the consoleAppender:

```
%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(18971){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx
```

As can be seen here:

[Debugger: detailed contents of the encoder pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcdq0.png)

Comment: Thanks, in other answer I added full working logback.xml with this pattern. It requires conversionRules elements from spring default.xml to work.

Comment: Why do you have the value `18971` explicitly in the pattern? Isn't this a meaningful variable which changes between different launches?

Answer (score 8):

Logging pattern can be configured using application.properties file

Example :

```
# Logging pattern for the console
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below pattern :

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${sys:PID} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40logger{1.} : %m%n%wEx
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can also customize the imported properties.

But beware that at least with spring boot 1.4.3 if you want to customize the properties imported from the defaults.xml, then the customization should be placed BEFORE the include.

For example this customizes the priority to 100 character wide:

```
<configuration scan="true">
    <property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN" value="%100p" />

    <!-- use Spring default values -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="hu" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

But this is NOT:

```
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- use Spring default values -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN" value="%100p" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="hu" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

[The spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging) has an example of the `logback.xml` that defines the default.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who'd like to use Łukasz Frankowski's answer (which looks like the cleanest solution here), but in a groovy version, the "problematic" `{$PID:- }` part can be expanded like in the following:

**logback-spring.groovy**

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
import org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ColorConverter
import org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter
import org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.INFO

conversionRule("clr", ColorConverter)
conversionRule("wex", WhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter)
conversionRule("wEx", ExtendedWhitespaceThrowableProxyConverter)

appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
    layout(PatternLayout) {
        def PID = System.getProperty("PID") ?: ''
        pattern = "%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID}){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx"
    }

}
root(INFO, ["STDOUT"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, adding following line to `resources/log4j2.properties` file

```yaml
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{ISO8601} - info: %msg%n ( your custom pattern goes here )
```